# Reading 2424 in Japanese

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, language, video-games

Celebrating twenty-four!

[image: coloured blobs animation]

The answer is numerical.

[image: grids of coloured blobs.]

Hint:

> Study the example shown.

Ambiguous Hint:

> Try to find twenty-four.

Comment: 20+24+2+4=50-rep bounty!

Comment: time to follow it.

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution, but as a start...

> I assumed we need to start by figuring out which color replaces each number in each image in order for the board to clear. The solutions are:

> YRBG GRYB RGBY RBGY YBGR
>  GYRB RGYB YGRB RBYG BRYG
>  BGRY YGBR YRGB BGYR GBRY

> Not sure if any of this is relevant, but note that none of them repeat, so these are 15 of the 24 possible permutations of colors. Also the one in the lower left is the one that corresponds with the numbering of the colors around the border of the main images.

Comment: Thanks for this! Also, it looks like ROT13(gur tnzr vf pnyyrq Chlb Chlb, juvpu vf bar jnl "gjb sbhe gjb sbhe" pna or ernq va Wncnarfr: uggcf://ra.jvxvcrqvn.bet/jvxv/Wncnarfr_jbeqcynl. Guvf rkcynvaf gur gvgyr).